# Copy/Pasting code that contains double quotation marks leads to broken code

Tags: files-and-directories, user-interface

Sometimes, when copy/pasting code that contains a string (double-quotes around it), the copy of the code fails to evaluate.

For example, the original code

```
NotebookEvaluate[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "Ion Masses.nb"}]]
```

sucessfully loads a file. But when I copy/paste this code somehwere else (let's say within the same notebook), and then evaluate that copy, I *sometimes* get the error:

```
Syntax::sntxf: "FileNameJoin[" cannot be followed by "{NotebookDirectory[],\" \\ \" \"\" Ion \"\" \"\" Masses \"\".\"\" nb \"\" \\ \" \"}]".
```

By converting the copied cell to "Input Form", I can see that Mathematica did some weird things with the double quotes:

```
NotebookEvaluate[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], \" \\ \" \" \" Ion \" \" \" \" \ Masses \" \".\" \" nb \" \" \\ \" \"}]]
```

How can I tell Mathematica to leave my filepath alone?

For reference, I am using Mathematica 10.0.1.0 (64 bit) on Windows 7.

### Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Create a "text" cell (ALT+7)
- Write one line of text `Hello`
- In the same cell, and underneath the text, write one line of code (which is going to be styled as text for now): `someCode["With Quotes"]`
- Highlight the code line and change the style to "Program"
- Highlight the code line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Make a new input cell
- Write one line of code into it: `nonsense;`
- With the cursor inside that cell, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
- Try to evaluate this cell. You'll see the error.
- Alternatively, right-click on the new, broken cell and "Convert To" -> "Input Form". You'll see the messy quotes.

I have seen this behaviour crop up in different ways, but this is a surefire way to reproduce it on my machine.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your issue. Can you be more specific about the steps that lead to the error? How are you copying and pasting (plain text, expression, input, etc.)?

Comment: I am copying plain text from one input cell to another. The behavious happens only sometimes.

Comment: I found out it is connected with the style of the double-quotes. Sometimes Mathematica uses styling to distinguis opening and closing quotation marks. The behaviour is inconsistent and somewhat unpredictable, but luckily there is an option to turn it off (see duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

When I repeat the steps in the original post, I occasionally get the behavior mentioned, but *not* every time.

Below is one way you can get the behavior every time.

### Input style

- Open a new notebook
- Type "hello" into an input cell (style is "input" by default)
- Highlight "hello" and copy/paste into Notepad
- In Notepad you will see simply "hello"

### Change to text style

- Go back to Mathematica; highlight "hello"; press ALT+7 to change style to "text"
- Copy/paste again into Notepad
- In Notepad you will see simply "hello"

### Change back to input style

- Go back to Mathematica; highlight "hello"; press ALT+9 to change style to "input"
- Copy/paste again into Notepad
- In Notepad you will see !(*\"\\"\")!(*\"hello\")!(*\"\\"\")